Securing Firebase requests
I’m currently developing a Telegram bot. Users send data to this bot, which is then received by my backend and subsequently sent to Firebase. I also have a frontend that directly fetches this data from Firebase to display it.
The issue I’m facing is that the frontend doesn’t require any API keys to fetch this data, implying that anyone could potentially send a request to the database. I’m looking for ways to secure this process.
Currently, my rules look like this:
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2033, 2, 13);
    }
  }
}

With these rules, I can restrict access for everyone, but that would also mean losing access myself. I’m looking for a solution that allows me to limit requests to Firebase without completely blocking access.
thx


Define the constraints for how users must be able to read or write documents in the database (we can't do that for you - these are based on the requirements of your app).  2) Implement those constraints using security rules.  I don't mean to snarky, but you haven't described the problem in nearly enough detail to get help.  The whole point of security rules is to implement the security requirements of your app, and if you don't have requirements, you can't write rules.


For common ways to secure access, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started and https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics
